# rounded corner with background image on Internet Explorer 6 and above

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I need rounded corner with background image for  or  on IE6 and above

I have tried
1. DD_roundies
2. pie.htc
3. google rounded-corners

any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, and what are your results with those, or rather, what's the problem with them (I don't know any of them)? Perhaps you could show us your code, so we can have a look at it?

Comment: none of the works, either there is rounded corner or background image

Comment: pie.htc works correct for me in all websites I used it. Probably you have to give us a live example to check what you do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one CSS3 feature which you can use for rounding up corners:

```
 .corner {
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

this class u refer in whichever browser you need but it will support IE9 and FF 3.6 so on which can support CSS3.